# Adding system.web applicationpool to web.config causes 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

I'm trying to add the following to my webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
</system.web>
```

However when I do so I get the following error.

```
The configuration section 'applicationPool' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

How can I add a section declaration for this?

Comment: Are you in Integrated or Classic mode? What version of .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can add that to a web.config file.  It should go in your Aspnet.config file.

[Web Settings Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560844.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set it to override pr. app under the sections

```
<system.webServer><httpRuntime>
```

and

```
<system.webServer><serverRuntime>
```

You can go into the IIS and check at the site under Configuration editor